# What is the difference between the patents register and patents journal in the UK?

Tags: united-kingdom, intellectual-property, legal-terms, patents

Whilst studying for my CIPA foundational exam 'UK Patent Law' I am coming across two terms: 'the patents journal' and 'the patents register'. The patents journal is published by the UK government every Wednesday (https://www.gov.uk/check-the-patents-journal), whereas I can't find the register, or at least I can't find any official government service under the name of the patents register, can anyone help?

Comment: Good question. I can guess at the answer (the journal probably regularly gives public notice, while the register is probably the definitive in house list of all patents outstanding), but since I don't solidly know, I won't attempt to post an answer, as we have other U.K. law experts at the site.

Comment: I would suggest you re-post this on patents.stackexchange.com. There have not been any questions on this site tagged "uk" and tagged "patents" with reasonably technical answers in the last 8 years. On Ask Patents there are participants including The Europeanist with specific expertise.